# Как сделать проверку на работу класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Делаю программу на Python 3.8.1 с помощью GUI Tkinter. Есть одно окно tk.Toplevel, которое должно открываться в одном единственном экземпляре, то есть таких окон не может быть запущено больше одного одновременно. Как сделать проверку на наличие одного открытого экземпляра этого окна при открытии следующего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enSO:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572905/check-if-a-toplevel-window-is-open-from-outer-function-in-python-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

wind2 = None

def startwind1():
    #global wind2
    #wind2 = None

    wind1 = tk.Tk()
    wind1.title('Window 1')

    w1button1 = ttk.Button(wind1,text='Launch Window 2', command=startwind2)
    w1button1.pack()

    w1button2 = ttk.Button(wind1,text='Check if Window 2 exists',command=checkwind2)
    w1button2.pack()

    wind1.mainloop()

def startwind2():
    global wind2

    wind2 = tk.Toplevel()
    wind2.title('Window 2')

def checkwind2():
    if (wind2 is not None) and wind2.winfo_exists():
        print('Window 2 exists')
    else:
        print('Window 2 not exists')

startwind1()
```